# Understanding Hadoop Simulator Mumak

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Recently I was trying to understand the working of Mumak (see, e.g., [MAPREDUCE-728](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAPREDUCE-728))

It basically takes a job trace and topology trace and simulates hadoop.
I couldn't understand how it assigns splits across nodes.
What does mumak mean by local map task and non-local task?

Answer (score 1):

In MapReduce there is the notion of "locality" which signifies how "far away" a task is running from the data it is working on. The best locality is running a task on a node that contains the data it needs. The second best locality is a node in the same rack as a node containing the data, etc...

Mumak has the ability to slow-down the tasks scheduled on non-local nodes by using the following settings in your configuration file:

```
<property>
    <name>mumak.scale.racklocal</name>
    <value>1.5</value>
    <description>Scaling factor for task attempt runtime of rack-local over
    node-local</description>
</property>

<property>
    <name>mumak.scale.rackremote</name>
    <value>1.8</value>
    <description>Scaling factor for task attempt runtime of rack-remote over
    node-local</description>
</property>
```